# How to insert a BibTeX reference into an R code chunk?

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex

I'd like to write something to generate a figure based on data for a few hundred references that I have in a BibTeX file.

I will be discussing some particular references in the body of the document.

I'd like to be able to make a plot using an R code chunk that inserts the numeric reference into the plot itself and keeps it consistent with the numeric citations that I have in the rest of the document.

I can insert a bibliographic reference into the body of the text using: [@citation_name] (which is then converted to the numeric citation).

Unfortunately, when I try to insert a bibliographic reference into a code chunk, like in the following, it just prints out "[@citation_name]".

````
    ```{r}
    plot(
      c(1,1)
    )
    text(1.1, "[@citation_name]")
    ```
````

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks!